# Showing Load image while waiting for an Excel download

Tags: javascript, performance, loading

I have a jsp where we we have links to some reports. When user clicks on the links he gets a report downloaded in excel files. The excel files are generated on the fly so there is my file metrics.jsp with set of links, links points to report.jsp which generates the excel. The problem here is that sometimes it takes a while to download the report and we want to show user that file is downloading and u need to wait. How do i do it.